# Constraints in a set of equations

Tags: boundary-conditions, constraint

I am currently working on a system of equations that is subject to a determinant constraint. Specifically, I have a matrix $B$ with $\det(B) = 0$, and I aim to construct a linear combination of its eigenvectors $\{p1, p2, p3, p4\}$ such that the linear combination satisfies a certain condition at $z = ±d/2$, i.e.,
$$
\text{if }f(z)=c1p_1(z)+c2p_2(z)+c3p_3(z)+c4p_4(z)\Rightarrow P(\pm d/2)=0.
$$

This construction ensures that at $z=d/2$, we have:
$$
f(d/2)=\left(0,C\det B,0,0\right)^T,
$$
where $C$ is a constant. While analytically $f(d/2)$ should be zero, my current code does not provide this result, because I don't know how to programm the constriction $\det B=0$.

This is my code:
To define the constants for the linear combination, I use:

```
cm1 = (c11 (-A1 + A2 + A1 E^(2 d l2) + A2 E^(2 d l2) - 
       2 A2 E^(d l1 + d l2)))/(-A1 E^(d l1) - A2 E^(d l1) + 
     2 A2 E^(d l2) + A1 E^(d l1 + 2 d l2) - A2 E^(d l1 + 2 d l2));
cp2 = -((c11 E^(-((d l1)/2) + (d l2)/
        2) (2 A1 E^(d l1) - A1 E^(d l2) - A2 E^(d l2) - 
         A1 E^(2 d l1 + d l2) + A2 E^(2 d l1 + d l2)))/(A1 E^(d l1) + 
       A2 E^(d l1) - 2 A2 E^(d l2) - A1 E^(d l1 + 2 d l2) + 
       A2 E^(d l1 + 2 d l2)));
cm2 = -((c11 E^(-((d l1)/2) + (d l2)/
        2) (-A1 + A2 - A1 E^(2 d l1) - A2 E^(2 d l1) + 
         2 A1 E^(d l1 + d l2)))/(-A1 E^(d l1) - A2 E^(d l1) + 
       2 A2 E^(d l2) + A1 E^(d l1 + 2 d l2) - A2 E^(d l1 + 2 d l2)));
```

The matrix $B$ is given by:

```
B = {{Exp[-l1*d/2], Exp[l1*d/2], Exp[-l2*d/2], Exp[l2*d/2]}, { 
    I A1  Exp[-l1*d/2], -I A1  Exp[l1*d/2], 
    I A2  Exp[-l2*d/2], -I A2  Exp[l2*d/2]}, {Exp[l1*d/2], 
    Exp[-l1*d/2], Exp[l2*d/2], 
    Exp[-l2*d/2]}, {I  A1  Exp[l1*d/2], -I A1  Exp[-l1*d/2], 
    I A2  Exp[l2*d/2], -I A2  Exp[-l2*d/2]}};
```

so that

```
In[]:=Det[B] // Simplify

Out[]:=E^(-d (l1 + l2)) (-A1^2 (-1 + E^(2 d l1)) (-1 + E^(2 d l2)) - 
   A2^2 (-1 + E^(2 d l1)) (-1 + E^(2 d l2)) + 
   2 A1 A2 (1 + E^(2 d l1) + E^(2 d l2) - 4 E^(d (l1 + l2)) + E^(
      2 d (l1 + l2))))
```

Finally, the linear combination is given by

```
p11[z_] := {{1}, {0}, {I  A1}, {0}} Exp[l1 z];
p12[z_] := {{1}, {0}, {-I A1}, {0}} Exp[-l1 z];
p21[z_] := {{1}, {0}, {I  A2}, {0}} Exp[l2 z];
p22[z_] := {{1}, {0}, {-I  A2}, {0}} Exp[-l2 z];
f[z_] := c11*p11[z] + cm1*p12[z] + cp2*p21[z] + cm2*p22[z]
```

Then:

```
In[]:= f[-d/2] // FullSimplify 
Out[]:={{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}
```

and

```
In[]:= f[d/2] // FullSimplify 
Out[]:={{0}, {0}, {-((
   I c11 E^(-((d l1)/
     2)) (A1^2 (-1 + E^(2 d l1)) (-1 + E^(2 d l2)) + 
      A2^2 (-1 + E^(2 d l1)) (-1 + E^(2 d l2)) - 
      2 A1 A2 (1 + E^(2 d l1) + E^(2 d l2) - 4 E^(d (l1 + l2)) + E^(
         2 d (l1 + l2)))))/(
   A1 E^(d l1) + A2 E^(d l1) - 
    2 A2 E^(d l2) + (-A1 + A2) E^(d (l1 + 2 l2))))}, {0}}
```

which has the form $\left(0,C\det B,0,0\right)^T$.

The question is: How can I apply the condition $\det B=0$ in my code to ensure that at $d=d/2 the vector will be null? My purpose is to plot each entry of the vector when numerical values for the constants are given.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

cm1 = (c11 (-A1 + A2 + A1 E^(2 d l2) + A2 E^(2 d l2) - 
       2 A2 E^(d l1 + d l2)))/(-A1 E^(d l1) - A2 E^(d l1) + 2 A2 E^(d l2) + 
     A1 E^(d l1 + 2 d l2) - A2 E^(d l1 + 2 d l2));
cp2 = -((c11 E^(-((d l1)/2) + (d l2)/2) (2 A1 E^(d l1) - A1 E^(d l2) - 
         A2 E^(d l2) - A1 E^(2 d l1 + d l2) + 
         A2 E^(2 d l1 + d l2)))/(A1 E^(d l1) + A2 E^(d l1) - 2 A2 E^(d l2) - 
       A1 E^(d l1 + 2 d l2) + A2 E^(d l1 + 2 d l2)));
cm2 = -((c11 E^(-((d l1)/2) + (d l2)/2) (-A1 + A2 - A1 E^(2 d l1) - 
         A2 E^(2 d l1) + 2 A1 E^(d l1 + d l2)))/(-A1 E^(d l1) - A2 E^(d l1) + 
       2 A2 E^(d l2) + A1 E^(d l1 + 2 d l2) - A2 E^(d l1 + 2 d l2)));

B = {{Exp[-l1*d/2], Exp[l1*d/2], Exp[-l2*d/2], 
    Exp[l2*d/2]}, {I A1 Exp[-l1*d/2], -I A1 Exp[l1*d/2], 
    I A2 Exp[-l2*d/2], -I A2 Exp[l2*d/2]}, {Exp[l1*d/2], Exp[-l1*d/2], 
    Exp[l2*d/2], Exp[-l2*d/2]}, {I A1 Exp[l1*d/2], -I A1 Exp[-l1*d/2], 
    I A2 Exp[l2*d/2], -I A2 Exp[-l2*d/2]}};

detB = Det[B] // Simplify;
```

When `detB == 0` then

```
cons = Solve[detB == 0, A1] // Simplify

(* {{A1 -> (A2 + A2 E^(2 d l1) + A2 E^(2 d l2) - 4 A2 E^(d (l1 + l2)) + 
      A2 E^(2 d (l1 + l2)) + 
      2 Sqrt[A2^2 (E^(d l1) - E^(d l2) - E^(d (2 l1 + l2)) + E^(
          d (l1 + 2 l2)))^2])/((-1 + E^(2 d l1)) (-1 + E^(
        2 d l2)))}, {A1 -> (A2 + A2 E^(2 d l1) + A2 E^(2 d l2) - 
      4 A2 E^(d (l1 + l2)) + A2 E^(2 d (l1 + l2)) - 
      2 Sqrt[A2^2 (E^(d l1) - E^(d l2) - E^(d (2 l1 + l2)) + E^(
          d (l1 + 2 l2)))^2])/((-1 + E^(2 d l1)) (-1 + E^(2 d l2)))}} *)
```

Note that Mathematica does not distinguish between row vectors and column vectors. The extra list brackets are not necessary.

```
p11[z_] := {1, 0, I A1, 0} Exp[l1 z];
p12[z_] := {1, 0, -I A1, 0} Exp[-l1 z];
p21[z_] := {1, 0, I A2, 0} Exp[l2 z];
p22[z_] := {1, 0, -I A2, 0} Exp[-l2 z];
f[z_] := c11*p11[z] + cm1*p12[z] + cp2*p21[z] + cm2*p22[z]

f[-d/2] // Simplify

(* {0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

With either constraint on `A1`

```
f[d/2] /. cons // Simplify

(* {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @bobhanlon . However, the final answer must be unique, and solving det B=0 for A1 gives two possible solutions, which do not satisfy the properties of the problem.

Comment: They both satisfy the problem that you described. To eliminate one of them, you would need to specify some constraint(s) that you have not specified.

Comment: The only constraints are det B=0, and the bounday conditions (from which the matrix B is constructed). All the constants (l1,l2, A1,A2, d) are given.

Comment: For `Det[B] == 0` requires the known constants (`{A1, A2, d, l1, l2}`) to have one of the relationships given by `cons /. Rule -> Equal`

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to the problem is to replace a portion of the determinant within the vector. Although this approach may not be considered elegant, it can be effective in solving the problem:

```
Simplify[
   f[-d/2]] /. {A1 A2 (1 + E^(2 d l1) + E^(2 d l2) - 
       4 E^(d (l1 + l2)) + E^(
       2 d (l1 + l2))) -> -((-A1^2 (-1 + E^(2 d l1)) (-1 + E^(
         2 d l2)) - A2^2 (-1 + E^(2 d l1)) (-1 + E^(2 d l2)))/
     2)} // MatrixForm
```